# C and static Code analysis: Is this safer than memcpy?

Tags: c, security, static-code-analysis, checkmarx

Is the following function safer than using memcpy?  Memcpy gives the following "Improper_Null_Termination" Error in Checkmarx static code analysis: The string  in  at line  is stripped of its terminating null-byte by  at .  However, if I use the following function, Checkmarx has no issue:

```
void myMemCpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t n) 
{ 
   // Typecast src and dest addresses to (char *) 
   char *csrc = (char *)src; 
   char *cdest = (char *)dest; 

   // Copy contents of src[] to dest[] 
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
       cdest[i] = csrc[i]; 
}
```

Are there any problems with using this function instead of memcpy()?

Comment: The problem is most likely in the code that uses `memcpy`, so please post it. (Cloning well-known library functions to silence the static code analyzer is a bit like casting away warnings.)

Comment: I don't see how that's any more safe than `memcpy`. If anything, you're obfuscating the `memcpy` so your code analyzer doesn't recognize it anymore and won't complain about its (mis)usage.

Comment: *"Improper_Null_Termination"* sounds to me like you are trying to copy a string. Do you maybe want [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)?

Comment: My guess is that the tool noticed that he wanted to copy the string, but he forgot to include the null terminator in the length.

Comment: No. `int i` not necessarily fit to `size_t n`. So this code even has a potential bug.

Comment: @AlexLop.  Not only that - `int` is signed, `size_t` is unsigned.

Comment: `memcpy` does not care about such termination. The problem is in the code using `memcpy`. Maybe you have code like: `memcpy(dst, src, strlen(src));` In any case the answer is no.

Comment: If `dest>src`, i.e overlap, it will overwrite itself.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Well `memcpy`requires that: "The memory areas must not overlap."

Answer (score 7):

> Is the following function safer than using memcpy?

No.  It's the same.  At best.

If anything, since code analyzers and compilers know what `memcpy()` does, this code is **less** safe.

Especially given the way you pass `size_t` and then improperly use an `int` loop counter:

```
void myMemCpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t n) 
{ 
   // Typecast src and dest addresses to (char *) 
   char *csrc = (char *)src; 
   char *cdest = (char *)dest; 

   // Copy contents of src[] to dest[] 
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
       cdest[i] = csrc[i]; 
}
```

On a 64-bit architecture with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `size_t`, that's going to fail spectacularly if `n` is a value over 2 gig.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the code? If no, why repeat it in an answer?

Comment: I wouldn't write "It's the same. At best." as the rest of the answer explains that it isn't the same.

Comment: @4386427 I'm assuming those other issues might be addressable, in which case it's the same as `memcpy()`.